# Is the sequence an almost convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

It is clear that the sequence $x_n$ defined by
$$
x_k = 
\begin{cases}
2 \quad\text{if } k\text{ is a perfect square number}    \\
0 \quad\text{if } k\text{ is even and not a perfect square} \\
1 \quad\text{if } k\text{ is odd and not a perfect square}
\end{cases}
$$
is not [statistically convergent](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a9e0/1205624e25f528def54e6fc81a2e95fe084c.pdf).

**My Qn:** Is it [almost convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_convergent_sequence)?

Comment: Yes, it is. Use Lorentz’s theorem and use the fact that among any $p$ consecutive numbers, there are $\leq \sqrt{p}$ perfect squares, and between $p/2-1$ and $p/2+1$ even/odd numbers.